# How to run the Aion Kernel Script

Tags: kernel, blockchain, cryptocurrency, aion

I get the following error when running the `./aion.sh` kernel script from here https://docs.aion.network/docs/native-node-1#section-precompiled-packages:

```
Warning! The linux kernel must be greater than or equal to version 4.
aion-kernal/test/aion.sh: line 17: lsb_release: command not found
Warning! Aion blockchain is fully compatible with Ubuntu distribution. Your current system is not Ubuntu distribution. It may have some issues.
aion-kernal/test/aion.sh: line 23: lsb_release: command not found
aion-kernal/test/aion.sh: line 24: [: : integer expression expected
chmod: ./rt/bin/*: No such file or directory
No Java runtime present, requesting install.
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Hi James, welcome to StackOverflow! What version of Ubuntu are you running? You can find out by running `lsb_release -a`.

Comment: It says `-bash: lsb_release: command not found`.

Comment: Can you try running `sw_vers -productVersion`?

Comment: It says `10.14.11`.

Comment: Yeahp, as Kimcodeashian's pointed out, looks like you're running a Mac. Take a look at Aion's docs for more info: https://docs.aion.network/docs/node-setup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to run the Aion kernel on a Mac. Unfortunately you can't do that right now, as the kernel is built to run on Ubuntu only.

You can try spinning up a kernel using [Docker though!](https://github.com/satran004/aion-fastvm-docker).